# Can't download modules Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to download modules through Prestashop module view and can't seem to download new modules. It just comes up with this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUE4H.png) and then doesn't allow me to login so I can't download the best sellers module which is needed for the site.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to need connect with prestashop addon marketplace to download any modules. see screenshot : http://prntscr.com/ehdwgv

Comment: Everytime I try and login I get this [link](http://prntscr.com/ehfxdv) and then doesn't let me login. But my internal and credentials are fine as they let me login on the prestashop site.

Comment: which specific prestashop 1.7 version do  you used?

Comment: Currently using 1.7.0.6, I only downloaded my copy yesterday.

Comment: I have check my 1.7.0.6 version and here everything is fine to install module without connect with addons marketplace. May be your server missing some of php extension or prestashop did not install properly.

Comment: Probably right, is there a way to get a copy of best sellers module that I can then install by dropping the folder into the admin section?

Comment: please download from here the module: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8RurKXcs8AeN3NnYzZpeWpCRnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You're an absolute star! Thank you very much.